# How can I require a password every visit for a Wordpress password protected page?

Tags: wordpress, password-protection

The password-protected page feature in Wordpress is great for what I need EXCEPT that it doesn't require the password every time and when I delete the password the user can still get in.

How can I get it to require the password every time?

Comment: lower the cookie lifetime to 1 minute, or terminate it when the user leaves the page

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are changing the visibility of a specific page or post to "password protected". You save this change after that.

You cannot use a password which is longer that 20 characters, have a look:
https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-password-protection/

If you experience that you do not have to enter a password, it probably is caused by your browser remembering the password in a cookie.

Please notice (from the link above):

> WordPress stores this password in a browser cookie so readers don’t
> have to re-enter passwords if they visit the same page multiple times.
> Furthermore, if multiple posts use the same password, the reader will
> only have to enter the password once to access every post (see caveat
> below).

So to answer your question, Wordpress Password-Protected page feature forces the user to enter a password to view the content, as you wish it to be.
The password is required every time unless a cookie has already been set.